# youtube_dl: проблема с сохранением файла в Докер

Tags: python-3.x, docker, youtube-dl

Всем привет.

Столкнулся с одним непонятным моментом при работе с библиотекой youtube_dl. Когда запускаю скрипт просто на локальной машине без Докера, то файлы скачиваются и сохраняются в нужной мне директории. Когда запускаю код в Докере, то в логах пишется, что скачивание идет и вроде бы в нужную мне директорию, но когда просматриваю внутри Докер-контейнера, то не вижу никаких файлов по этому адресу.

Код для сохранения такой:

```
outtmpl = '/usr/src/project/telegram_crop_video/files/' + '%(id)s.%(ext)s'

ydl_opts_start = {
    'format': 'best',
    'playliststart:': 1,
    'playlistend': 4,
    'outtmpl': outtmpl,
    'nooverwrites': True,
    'no_warnings': False,
    'ignoreerrors': True,
}

with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts_start) as ydl:
    ydl.download([url])
```

docker-compose такой:

```
services:
  bot:
    build: .
    container_name: telegram_crop_video
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    command: python3 main.py
    volumes:
      - './files:/usr/src/project/telegram_crop_video/files'
```

Права в докере на директорию:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   64 Oct 27 20:22 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Oct 27 20:27 ..
root@b615cc7321f6:/usr/src/project/telegram_crop_video/files#
```

Comment: какой командой запускаете это? как проверяете, что файлы существуют ?

Comment: запускаю как docker-compose up. проверяю наличие путем захода в контейнер - docker exec -ti [image] /bin/bash, а затем перехожу в директорию cd files и смотрю через ls -la